# Confusing ternary in - Python

Tags: python, iteration, conditional-statements, ternary

Assuming that my list has only `str` and `None`, and I want to check assign lowered strings into another variable but if it's uppered or None, it should be rendered as None.

The code to checking for `None` and `str.isupper()` works:

```
for i in [None,'foo',None,'FOO',None,'bar']:
  x = None if i is None or i.isupper() else i
  print x
```

but the negated condition didn't work:

```
for i in [None,'foo',None,'FOO',None,'bar']:
  x = i if i is not None or i.isupper() else None
  print x
```

It returns `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isupper'
```

- **Why is that so?**
- **Other than the ternary assignment in a loop, is there another way to perform the same operation?**

Comment: Ternary operator makes code harder to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing if `i is not None or i.isupper()`. This doesn't work when `i` *is* `None`:

```
(i is not None) or (i.isupper())
```

is evaluated lazily; first the left is evaluated, and only if `False` is the second argument evaluated. The first is only `False` if `i` is `None`, so the right-hand expression is only ever evaluated as `None.isupper()`.

Use `and` instead, and negate the `isupper()` test:

```
x = i if i is not None and not i.isupper() else None
```

The above expression is the proper logical inversion of `i is None or i.isupper()`.

Alternatively use `not (..)` around your original expression:

```
x = i if not (i is None or i.isupper()) else None
```

Because you are using a regular `for` loop, there is no need to use a conditional expression here; the following, assigning to the existing loop variable `i`, suffices:

```
for i in [None,'foo',None,'FOO',None,'bar']:
      if i and i.isupper():
          i = None
      print i
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code that returns an `AttributeError`, it's because if i **is** none, it goes on to the second part of the `or` statement and checks `i.isupper()`, but `None` doesn't have an `isupper()` method, hence the error.

May I suggest a different approach?

```
items = [None,'foo',None,'FOO',None,'bar']

def splitItems(items, test):
    trueItems = []
    falseItems = []
    for item in items:
        if test(item):
            trueItems.append(item)
        else:
            falseItems.append(item)
    return trueItems, falseItems

trueItems, falseItems = splitItems(items, lambda i:i is None or i.isupper())
print "uppercase or None:", trueItems
print "lowercase:", falseItems
# uppercase or None: [None, None, 'FOO', None]
# lowercase: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: I'd **never** use a conditional expression for the side-effects.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you explain what you mean?  I don't understand.

Comment: The conditional expression results in a value, **normally**. But you are not using it for the expression result. You are using it to call `.append()` on one of two lists. Don't, just use a normal `if` / `else` construct for such cases.

Comment: You are using the expression construct for the side-effects and that leads to confusion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok - it doesn't seem confusing to me - it just looks like shorthand/syntactic sugar for an if/else statement.  But I'll defer to you and change it, looks fine either way to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I agree, writing a condition like `dictvar.pop(key) % 1` to both test on and remove a key in a dict is poor practice. But I think this answer is a reasonable list partitioning strategy, not unlike groupby. There are no side effects, the original items list is unchanged. Given a list and a condition, return two lists containing those elements that match the condition and those elements that fail.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - after looking at the original version, I see what you are talking about, and concur 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Brionius' *edited* answer, here is an even more general form of it, returning a dict of items from a list, keyed by the value returned by a discriminating function (could return more than just True or False).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def groupByEval(seq, fn):
    ret = defaultdict(list)
    for item in seq:
        ret[fn(item)].append(item)
    return dict(ret.iteritems())


test = [None,'foo',None,'FOO',None,'bar']
print groupByEval(test, lambda x: x is not None)
print groupByEval(test, lambda x: 0 if x is None else len(x))
print groupByEval(test, lambda x: x is not None and x.isupper())
print groupByEval(test, lambda x: x if x is None else sum(x.lower().count(c) for c in 'aeiou'))
```

Giving:

```
{False: [None, None, None], True: ['foo', 'FOO', 'bar']}
{0: [None, None, None], 3: ['foo', 'FOO', 'bar']}
{False: [None, 'foo', None, None, 'bar'], True: ['FOO']}
{1: ['bar'], 2: ['foo', 'FOO'], None: [None, None, None]}
```

Brionius' solution could then be implemented as:

```
def splitItems(seq, condition):
    ret = groupByEval(seq, condition)
    return ret.get(True,[]), ret.get(False,[])
```